# Yum DuplicateOptionError Proxy

Tags: linux, centos, yum

I don't know exactly what I am doing :(. I try to patch CentOS using BigFix. Somehow there is an error log from the target. Here's the part of log:

```
    47790    : 2019-06-13 23:06:46 : INFO     : 01 setup and request repomd.xml
47790    : 2019-06-13 23:06:46 : CRITICAL : Unexpected error!
47790    : 2019-06-13 23:06:46 : CRITICAL : Exception type: <class 'configparser.DuplicateOptionError'>
47790    : 2019-06-13 23:06:46 : CRITICAL : While reading from '/etc/yum.conf' [line 14]: option 'proxy' in section 'main' already exists
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 47, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 41, in main
  File "bfyum/cli/setup.py", line 71, in do
  File "bfyum/yum.py", line 24, in __init__
  File "bfyum/config.py", line 25, in __init__
  File "bfyum/config.py", line 71, in load_sys_yum_config
  File "configparser.py", line 672, in read
  File "configparser.py", line 1070, in _read
configparser.DuplicateOptionError: While reading from '/etc/yum.conf' [line 14]: option 'proxy' in section 'main' already exists
47792    : 2019-06-13 23:06:46 : DEBUG    : Exit code file is not None, and /var/opt/BESClient/EDRDeployData//EDR_ExitCode_19067901 is a file. Reading file ...
47792    : 2019-06-13 23:06:46 : DEBUG    : Exit code file, first row is not 0. Will not continue.
47792    : 2019-06-13 23:06:46 : ERROR    : Lock repo data will not continue, last command exit code is not 0
47795    : 2019-06-13 23:06:46 : DEBUG    : Exit code file is not None, and /var/opt/BESClient/EDRDeployData//EDR_ExitCode_19067901 is a file. Reading file ...
47795    : 2019-06-13 23:06:46 : DEBUG    : Exit code file, first row is not 0. Will not continue.
47795    : 2019-06-13 23:06:46 : ERROR    : Dependency resolution will not continue, last command exit code is not 0
47799    : 2019-06-13 23:06:47 : DEBUG    : Exit code file is not None, and /var/opt/BESClient/EDRDeployData//EDR_ExitCode_19067901 is a file. Reading file ...
47799    : 2019-06-13 23:06:47 : DEBUG    : Exit code file, first row is not 0. Will not continue.
47799    : 2019-06-13 23:06:47 : ERROR    : yum command not continue, last command exit code is not 0
```

It seems there is something wrong with the proxy in Yum configuration, duplicate? Please give some hints or explanation,  What should I do?

Thanks.

Comment: Solved. I just opened yum.conf and remove the duplicate line. thx

Comment: Can you please put that into an answer? You shouldn't be answering questions in comments.